# Prompt a warning message when user input contains incomplete data

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to create a dashboard of monthly prices of different commodities using shiny. However, there's some part of my data with incomplete information such as below:

```
Commodity   Year   Month    Price
Tomatoes   2018     1         29
Tomatoes   2018     2         27
Tomatoes   2018     3         33
Tomatoes   2018     5         28
Tomatoes   2018     7         31
```

There are months where the price was not recorded. Thus, resulting to an incomplete plot. Now, I want to prompt a warning message to the user indicating that the selected commodity has an incomplete data. Is there any way to do this? Follow up question, is there any way for me to know such discrepancies when I group_by a certain data? Thanks!

Comment: The data you posted looks complete.. but [this](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/notifications.html) might apply.

Comment: Hi, I am expecting my data to be complete in a sense where the number of months is 12 per year. There are also times where  the price for specific month was not recorded (in the example above, aside from missing the months 8 to 12, the price for the 6th month was not recorded).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option might be to prompt a message when the number of months is less than 12,

```
df <- data.frame(Commodity = rep("Tomatoes", 5),
                 Year = rep(2018, 5),
                 Month = c(1, 2, 3, 5, 7),
                 Price = c(19, 17, 33, 28, 31))

missing_months <- df %>% 
  group_by(Commodity, Year) %>%
  # count the number of months for which you have data... assuming no NAs for Price
  summarize(n_months_w_data = n()) %>%
  filter(n_months_w_data < 12)
```

You could then use the information in `missing_months` to prompt when/if a warning message should be sent to the user (e.g. if `nrow(missing_months) == 0` then no warning needs be thrown).